# HttpWebRequest System.Net.WebException thrown when hitting HTTPS web server

Tags: c#, .net, apache, ssl

We are in the process of moving our Apache based web API to a different location, and because of this the IP is changing. The new web API machine is using the same Apache version, has the exact same vhost.conf and SSL configurations, and it using the same certificate files as the old web API.

As soon as we changed DNS to point to the new web API machine, we noticed the error messages below in our C# 4.5 WCF service running on Windows 2012 R2 Servier(i'll call it the WCF service machine from now on). I'm able to hit the new web API landing page fine via chrome on my local desktop, via https, which leads me to believe this is a specific problem on the WCF service machine. I also did a sanity check to ensure I can telnet into the new IP and port from the WCF service machine.

Does .NET 4.5 do any caching of certificate files, and if the IP changes, it throws up?

**Note. The WCF service is the client in this scenario, and the Apache based web API is the server, and the two are communicating via HTTPS**

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

SSL version directly from our .conf file

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
```

WCF service code accessing the Apache web API

```
        authServiceURI = authServiceBaseURI + "/v1/me";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(authServiceURI);
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + bearerToken;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (response)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
                JProperty usernameProp = jObj.Property("user_name");
                JProperty clientidProp = jObj.Property("client_id");

                if(usernameProp != null) 
                {
                    string username = usernameProp.Value.ToString();
                    string clientID = clientidProp.Value.ToString();
                    UserService us = new UserService();
                    User u = us.GetByLogin(username);

                    if (u != null)
                    {
                        authenticatedToken = new AuthToken();
                        authenticatedToken.AuthenticatedUser = u;
                        authenticatedToken.AuthMethod = AuthType.OAuth2;
                        authenticatedToken.ClientID = clientID;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add some code to demonstrate how you call the API? And just to be clear, the only change is at DNS level, the old API remains reachable?

Comment: Yes. The only change is at the DNS level. We were able to switch back DNS to the old server and it now works fine; however, still need to figure this out so we can complete the migration. I'll add code in a few.

Comment: Are you using an old version of SSL or something currently? Some new versions of windows might have different support

Comment: Added WCF service code, and also the version of SSL we are using to the post description. Thanks, guys.

Comment: When using DNS always use the Computer Name and not the IP address.  When the IP gets updated you may need to use >IPCONFIG/renew

Comment: @jdweng to clarify, the WCF service is the client, and the Apache based web API is the server, and the two are communicating over HTTPS.

Comment: You just asked : "Does .NET 4.5 do any caching of certificate files, and if the IP changes, it throws up?"  The Net Library uses the same location for certificates as your browsers in the User Temporary folder.  Deleting the browser cookie history may solve issue.  After you change the DNS location the cookie may still contain old info.  Your IP Routing and the DNS are probably different and if IP works it doesn't mean DNS will work since the DNS location comes from a DNS server and the routing is based on IP address and mask.

Comment: What happens if you ping the Apache server using its DNS name?. Are you seeing the new IP or old IP. You can clear the DNS cache in WCF service machine with `ipconfig /flushdns` from an admin command prompt (in case the old IP address is still cached and used).

Comment: Technically, both the old and new Apache web API point to the same internal sub components, so even if the WCF service was still resolving to the old web API, it still should have worked. We purposefully did our migration this way so it would be seamless, and we would disable the old web API once we confirmed it is no longer being hit. I'll look into what @jdweng mentioned and try clearing the cookie/certificate history and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken, and the new web API was using a slightly different ssl.conf than the old web API server. The new server supported TLS1.1 and up, and the old supported TLS1.0 and up. Apparently, C# .NET 4.5 does not by default support TLS1.1, and you need to explicitly set the SecurityProtocol if you want to communicate via TLS1.1.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```